# Building a matrix procedurally

Tags: matrix, procedural-programming

The following code is syntactically correct (I receive no error message) but it does not print the matrix I am expecting. In fact, it does not print anything at all. I expect:

$\begin{bmatrix}
d & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -c & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1/b-1/c
\end{bmatrix}$

```
pcomb[n_]:= (
  matt=ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
  matt[[1, 1]] = d;
  matt[[1, 2]] = 1;
  For [q = 1, q < n - 2, q++, 
    If[EvenQ[q - 1],
      matt[[q + 1, q]] = 1;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 1]] = -c;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 2]] = 1;
    ,
      matt[[q + 1, q]] = 1;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 1]] = d;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 2]] = 1;]];
  matt[[n - 1, n - 2]] = 1;
  matt[[n - 1, n - 1]] = -c;
  matt[[n - 1, n]]= -1;
  matt[[n, n - 1]] = 1;
  matt[[n,n]] = 1/b-1/c;
  matt;)

pcomb[7]
```

I've checked out the following tutorial but did not find it useful to pinpoint my mistake. I also looked at Wolfram's reference for procedural programming.

http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/pure-functions/

Comment: Try ending with `matt)` instead of `matt;)`

Comment: You might want to consider using `SparseArray[]`: `With[{n = 7}, SparseArray[{{n - 1, n} -> -1, {n, n} -> 1/b - 1/c, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, Band[{1, 1}, {n - 1, n - 1}] -> {d, -c}}, {n, n}]]`. Where did this tridiagonal matrix come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semi-colon at the end of the line `matt;` ensures that your function `pcomb` doesn't actually return anything. For a multiline function, you want to use `Function` (and/or `Module` or `Block`) instead of parentheses. Writing instead:

```
pcomb = Function[{n},
   Block[{matt = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]},
    matt[[1, 1]] = d;
    matt[[1, 2]] = 1;
    For[q = 1, q < n - 2, q++, If[EvenQ[q - 1], matt[[q + 1, q]] = 1;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 1]] = -c;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 2]] = 1;,
      matt[[q + 1, q]] = 1;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 1]] = d;
      matt[[q + 1, q + 2]] = 1;]];
    matt[[n - 1, n - 2]] = 1;
    matt[[n - 1, n - 1]] = -c;
    matt[[n - 1, n]] = -1;
    matt[[n, n - 1]] = 1;
    matt[[n, n]] = 1/b - 1/c;
    matt
    ]
   ];
```

gets the desired output from `pcomb[7]`.